# Disabling the review queue/prompts when review privilege is revoked?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-suspension

When a person is banned from review, is it better to disable the review menu, or the prompt for review queue of pending tasks?

Currently, the system menu continues to prompt a person of the new review tasks as they come and go, which is inconsistent. Since a person is banned, there is no reason to update him/her about pending review tasks.

Comment: Similarly, the "review" link in the top-bar won't show up if you don't have the rep for any of the queues.

Comment: I've seen a dupe for this question recently ...

Comment: A better solution: Don't get banned or suspended, and this won't be an issue for you. :D

Comment: @KenWhite Just like a better solution is to not need Dark Mode.  Doesn't invalidate the question

Answer (score 9):

If the links were simply removed then we'd just end up with support requests of people asking why the links are gone.  They wouldn't know that the links were gone because they were banned.

Comment: @TingL If you grey it out then they'll have no idea *why* it's greyed out.  They need to know that they're banned, and why their banned, and the best way to do that is to provide an appropriate message when they go to the Review page.

Comment: Unless you add a tool-tip, though that might not be the best option. I'd rather try to open the door and get denied than not be able to touch the door knob.

Comment: @gunr2171 That wouldn't be a practical way to include a ban message, links to failed audits/bad reviews, a detailed explanation, etc.  Tooltips are for information that's both very short, doesn't need to be given much attention, and where reading it is really optional.  None of that applies here.

Comment: @TingL What's the point in going out of your way to hide it?  If you know that you're banned for reviewing, then don't spend your time checking what the current review counts are.

Comment: @Servy, nobody is going out of their way to hide anything. It's just the current system of prompting doesn't make any sense. I think something should be done about it, regardless of whether it's hiding it or disabling it.

Comment: @TingL Nothing is *currently* going out of its way to hide anything.  You're proposing a change in that we go out of our way to hide the review count.

Comment: @TingL How is the issue not being addressed?  It's addressed *in a different way than you would like*, namely that the actions are shown and an error message is provided, rather than hiding the action entirely.  They're two different ways of solving a problem, and both have their place in certain contexts.  In this one the former was chosen, and I feel it's the correct *choice*.

Comment: @TingL Which brings me back to my [original comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275991/hiding-the-review-queue-prompts-when-review-privilege-is-banned/275992?noredirect=1#comment113530_275992).  What's the point of going out of our way to hide that information?  What value is gained by doing that?  You haven't actually answered that question.  If you want to propose a change you're quite right that meta is the place to do it, but you do need to justify your proposal and explain why it would be beneficial.

Comment: You don't just get a reminder that you're banned from reviewing. There's a link on that page that takes you to the reviews you failed so you can see *exactly* what you did wrong. This is critical to improving on future reviews.

Comment: @Servy, I think we would have to agree that we disagree, now that you are resorting to personal attacks. I've stated clearly, the value is to reduce unnecessary tension and inconsistency of the system. You can disagree with that.

Comment: @BilltheLizard What about the prompt that 27 new reviews needing your attention? What's the point in there?

Comment: @TingL Asking you to justify the reason for your proposed change is a personal attack?  Really?

Comment: @TingL If you want to hide it then you need to justify why it should be hidden, rather than Bill needing to justify why it should be shown.

Comment: @TingL They do need your attention. The reviews you failed just need your attention more urgently.

Answer (score 1):

The review queue number is a **community notification** which indicates that review tasks are available.

It is not a personal notification meant specifically for you. It does not mean that you were assigned review tasks that you cannot complete.