# Pending Edits notification shown while banned from reviewing

Tags: feature-request, review-suspension

There is a brown reminder badge near the review menu entry, which shows the number of pending edit reviews. This is a good way to draw attention to the review queues.

However, this number is also shown if the user is currently suspended from reviewing. This leads to additional clicks to the banned message page or a user who shakes head because he is banned and cannot help (when it seems important to).

I would consider it a bug to show this, but I will classify it as a feature-request... I think there is also a similar request ([hide it when daily limit is reached](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269957/hide-x-suggested-edits-pending-approval-notifications-when-daily-limit-has-be)).

Comment: I had a similar feature-request, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275991/disabling-the-review-queue-prompts-when-review-privilege-is-revoked, which is rather badly received.