# Suggested edits notification not taking filter into account

Tags: feature-request

Currently, the pending suggested edits icon next to review does not take into account your filter for that review queue.

This results in having the review icon permanently showing, and hides the instances of pending suggested edits I'm actually interested in.

Could we have this notification show a count of the queue *including* our filter?

[image]

Comment: Think on a global scale.  You're not the only person getting that notification.  You're also not the only person to have filters on their review preferences.   Consider the requests that would have to do filtering; it's probably not a *lot* of extra work, but that adds up for every account on Stack Overflow with review filters.  What would make adding that support worthwhile to do on a global scale?

Comment: @Makoto I understand it's a global notification, but I wouldn't imagine there would be a huge performance hit showing a count by the filter. No more so than the inbox or achievements notifications, I would imagine. If it really *would* be a huge performance drain, then sure, it's not worth it.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to tease out.  How often does that update?  How often does that notification refresh?  Dunno about those ramifications, but I'm not sure I see the benefit from that alone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That notification is cached globally per site for performance, since it's shown on every single page (at least, for 2k+ users). So at present, not only does it not take into account your *queue filter*, it doesn't even take into account tasks you are *ineligible to review at all, ever* (such as close reviews on your own question, NAA flags on your own answer, and so forth), tasks you *already reviewed* (that aren't finished), or tasks *you would not be shown* (but that would still allow actions; e.g. you already skipped, plus a few others). For that matter… [Pending Edits notification shown while banned from reviewing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280811/pending-edits-notification-shown-while-banned-from-reviewing).

Removing the caching is [not considered viable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191638/notify-users-of-possible-reviews-on-toolbar/230726#comment758002_230726).