# A single pending change to review which is your change

Tags: bug, documentation, review-queues

When you are trying to review a pending proposed changes, but this (or these) pending change is both the only pending change in the category and your own change, you get the following message:

[image]

Although there is actually one pending change to review (which is your change).

In the flow above, a *You cannot review your own pending changes* or a similar message will describe more accurately what's happening.

Comment: Seems fine to me. There are no currently pending items (for you) to review. Having a message 'You cannot review your own pending changes' would be confusing; no one specified *asked* to review their own changes.

Comment: @Rob: AFAIK other queues do not show your own items in those summary numbers at all.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Those numbers are globally cached, so I'm pretty sure that's incorrect. In fact, you're the one who answered [my question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311698/suggested-edits-notification-not-taking-filter-into-account) about it regarding filters :)

Comment: @Rob: This is (I think) actually different, since the new topbar's review menu actually uses AJAX to load your own personalized /review, which *isn't* globally cached and *does* discount your own items.

Comment: Fixing the number of pending reviews (if we can) sounds like the way to go here rather than tweaking the message. I agree with Rob - doing the latter would likely end up being more confusing.