# How to hide pending review?

Tags: support, user-experience

Is there a way to hide this random-like number from appearing?
[image]

Since I got that badge, every time I visit Stack Overflow I look at it. Another question, does this seem like a good UX practice?

Comment: It's the number of active suggested edits in the review queue. You could always use a userscript to get rid of it if it really bugs you.

Comment: Just be proud of it!

Comment: related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280811/pending-edits-notification-shown-while-banned-from-reviewing and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269957/hide-x-suggested-edits-pending-approval-notifications-when-daily-limit-has-be

Comment: Maybe a stylish rule can fix this for you: `.unread-count { display: none;}`